# Convergence that preserves smoothness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

One of the advantages of uniform convergence is that it preserves continuity (among other properties). Unfortunately, it does not preserve derivability. Is there a convergence mode preserving it?

Comment: Locally uniform convergence of all derivatives.

Comment: Alex, what is the point of having a tag for derivability?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I believe that there are questions that only enquire about derivability in its various forms (Fréchet, Gâteaux), differentiability on manifolds, everything that should fit under the general umbrella of "derivability". Plus, think about it: if you remove this tag from my question, the remaining ones would never suggest a potential reader that it deals with derivability in an essential way.

Comment: We have [tag:differentiability], which is synonymous with [tag:derivatives]. We also have some derivative-specific (e.g. Gateaux) tags. There's no need for yet another tag about derivability.

Comment: (It is a good idea in general to actively search for old tags, and not just decide that there is a new tag needed. If you want to further inform the reader that this question is about derivability, then perhaps a better title is in order, too.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, I had seen the "derivatives" tag when composing my question, but it seemed to me that it was created with something else in mind. Anyway, I have removed the original tag and replaced it with "derivatives", everything should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers with $a<b$. Suppose that $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ (considering one-sided derivatives at the endpoints). Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be any functions.

> **Claim:** If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f'=g$.

*Proof:* By uniform convergence, $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, one has $$f_n(x)-f_n(a)=\int_a^xf_n'(t)\,\mathrm dt\quad\text{for every $x\in[a,b]$ and every $n\in\mathbb N$.}$$
Next, observe that
\begin{align*}
&\left|f(x)-f(a)-\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|=\left|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(a)-f(a)+f_n(x)-f_n(a)-\int_a^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\\
=&\,\left|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(a)-f(a)+\int_a^x[f_n'(t)-g(t)]\,\mathrm dt\right|\\
\leq&\,|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(a)-f(a)|+\int_a^x|f_n'(t)-g(t)|\,\mathrm dt\\
\leq&\,\sup_{y\in[a,b]}|f(y)-f_n(y)|+\sup_{y\in[a,b]}|f_n(y)-f(y)|+(x-a)\times\sup_{y\in[a,b]}|f_n'(y)-g(y)|\to 0
\end{align*}
because of uniform convergence. It follows that $$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$ By the fundamental theorem of calculus again, one has that $f$ is differentiable (given that $g$ is continuous) and $f'=g$. $\blacksquare$